# Load a JS File before everything else in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Meteor loads files based on alphabetical order, depth of the directory and whether the file's parent directory is named `/lib`.

If I have a `.js` file defining an object containing global settings of the app that needs to be set before any other files uses them, how can this be done except for putting it in nested `lib` directories?

Comment: can you elaborate why it is not sufficient to call the file `a.js` and put it into the `lib` folder? do you want it to be loaded on both the client and the server before everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did and was a work around only no the proper way to do it because was for a prototype. Was named with an underscore at the beginning of the file so will be call at the very first.

```
_myfile.js
secondfile.js
whateverfile.js
```

Not the best solution but works.

Comment: As of 0.7.2, this is actually a good solution.  Current load order is a bit hard to work with: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-test-dir-order  Core team plans to improve it.  Another solution is to make your own package where you can explicitly define load order.